# Ansible gce Module Does not Allow Provisioning Multiple SSH Keys in Metadata

Tags: ansible, google-compute-engine

I've read the documentation on storing and [retrieving metadata for GCE instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata/overview). It states the format is:

```
"user1:ssh-rsa mypublickey user1@host.com\nuser2:ssh-rsa mypublickey user2@host.com"
```

If I use newlines, the [gce module](https://web.archive.org/web/20180706043616/http://ansible-manual.readthedocs.io:80/en/latest/gce_module.html) fails to deploy the instance because it doesn't accept the string with newlines in it (single or double quotes makes no difference).

When I try an array with the format, it deploys the instance, but ignores the second public key:

```
{'ssh-keys': [ 
      'user1:ssh-rsa mypublickey user1@host.com', 
      'user2:ssh-rsa mypublickey user2@host.com'
   ]
 }
```

Is my formatting incorrect? Is it just not supported with the gce module?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like (multi line ansible variable including new lines)

```
ssh-keys: |
      'user1:ssh-rsa mypublickey user1@host.com' 
      'user2:ssh-rsa mypublickey user2@host.com'
```

see if that helps.